# MySQL Event Scheduler

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I have set 1 mysql events that transferring all data with `0` flag from one table to another (table 2) every 12 hours, then update query to set as `1` the flag after transferring. `INSERT` and `UPDATE` is on one event process.

My problem is, all transferred data have duplicate on the table 2 that looks like 2 event is running.

Any idea?

Here is my event codes:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE
    EVENT
    IF NOT EXISTS
    event_transfer
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 12 HOUR
    STARTS '2018-08-10 06:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
    ENABLE
```

`DO

BEGIN


INSERT INTO dbsample.tblmirror (Column1, Column2, Column3)
       (SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
               FROM tblmaster
                    WHERE is_transfer = 0);

UPDATE dbsample.tblmaster
   SET is_transfer = 1
       WHERE is_transfer = 0;


END |

DELIMITER;`

Comment: When you SHOW EVENTS is there only 1 present?

Comment: Please post your event code.

Comment: Yes, I already checked it and there is only 1

Comment: Then post all the code and create table statements, please.

Comment: I already updated my post

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: no triggers involved

Comment: No duplicate event, simple code, no triggers - I doubt that the problem lies here at all.

Comment: @joearg Any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting P.Salmon:

> No duplicate event, simple code, no triggers - I doubt that the problem lies here at all.

P.Salmon is right here, and it would be good, if you figured out, what other job is doing this.
But, you can also avoid this problem in another way. Since you don't want to have duplicates, there is a way to detect duplicates, right? Be it, that the combination of those 3 columns has to be unique, or whatever, then indicate so in your database.

Create a unique index (or primary key) on the columns that make each row unique.

Then, instead of a simple `INSERT` you do `INSERT IGNORE`, and voilà, you won't have duplicates any more.

Quoting the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE modifier, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.